# Langcain Chromadb

Tags: node.js, langchain

```
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "langchain/embeddings/openai";
import { environment } from "../../../environment/environment";
import { Chroma } from "langchain/vectorstores/chroma";

let embedding = new OpenAIEmbeddings({ openAIApiKey: environment.llm.open_ai_api_key })

let dbConfig = { url: "http://localhost:8000", collectionName: "openai_collection" }

const vectorStore = await Chroma.fromExistingCollection(embedding, dbConfig)

const response = await vectorStore.similaritySearch("past postion attributes");
```

Error: Please install chromadb as a dependency with, e.g. `npm install -S chromadb`

I already installed Chromadb but I still chroma from langchain/vectorstore throws error

```
npm list chromadb
   ├── chromadb@1.5.11
   └─┬ langchain@0.0.152
     └── chromadb@1.5.11
```

Comment: please share output of npm list chromadb

Comment: @ZKS ├── chromadb@1.5.11
└─┬ langchain@0.0.152
  └── chromadb@1.5.11

Answer (score 0):

Some people say rolling back to chromadb 1.5.6 helps: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/7260#issuecomment-1752151558 It solved it for me.